# How to change Julia kernel in Jupyter note?

Tags: julia, jupyter

I installed Julia v1.3 and connected it to Jupyter. However, it doesn't seem to work well on my Windows 10, so I am trying to switch to Julia v1.0. However, the nootbook only shows Julia 1.3, which is already uninstalled. How can I make Jupyter connect to v1.0 instead?

[image]

Comment: Open up Julia 1.0 on your computer, do `using IJulia ` and then `notebook`.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to the solution in Logan's comment:

The IJulia build script registers kernels with Jupyter. You can do:

```
] build IJulia
```

in Julia 1.0, after which the kernel should be registered and show up in subsequent starts of Jupyter.

Comment: Thanks to Nils for pointing out the registration! Using build is apparently crucial, because otherwise you may start notebook, but it won't know of anything you have newly installed.